# This Row already belongs to another table error when trying to add rows?

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable which has some rows and I am using the select to filter the rows to get a collection of DataRows which I then loop through using foreach and add it to another DataTable, but it is giving me the error "This Row already belongs to another table".  Here is the code:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dtAllOrders"];
DataTable dtSpecificOrders = new DataTable();

DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2");

foreach (DataRow dr in orderRows)
{
    dtSpecificOrders.Rows.Add(dr); //Error thrown here.
}
```

Comment: great question; I get confused about rows and tables belonging to other containers

Answer (score 369, accepted):

You need to create a new `Row` with the values from `dr` first. A `DataRow` can only belong to a single `DataTable`.

You can also use `Add` which takes an array of values:

```
myTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
```

Or probably even better:

```
// This works because the row was added to the original table.
myTable.ImportRow(dr);

// The following won't work. No data will be added or exception thrown.
var drFail = dt.NewRow()
drFail["CustomerID"] = "[Your data here]";
// dt.Rows.Add(row); // Uncomment for import to succeed.
myTable.ImportRow(drFail);
```

Comment: Can I use ImportRow as an alernative? and Why would .NET only not allow you to have the same DataRow for different DataTables?  Is this by design?

Comment: Thanks for the above snippet.  I was just about to ask if I had 100 rows, would I have to type all of them out?

Comment: Heh I just realized ImportRow, edit my answer and you all beat me to it. But yea I'd recommend that approach as it will copy the row for you

Comment: If I do it the dr.ItemArray way, would I still need to create a NewRow?

Comment: `ImportRow` din work for me. But Add Rows did! Thanksssssssssss

Comment: ImportRow will not work if the row you import is a reference to the row in the source table.  ItemArray works if you use the source row, but you have to remember to add the row to the destination before you remove the row from the source, otherwise it complains the row has been removed and cannot find the data.

Comment: Does anyone have an article where it describes the disadvantage of DataTable vs other .Net collections(List,Dictionary,ObservableCollection) ?

Comment: `.ImportRow()` didn't work for me because I didn't do `.Clone()` or create columns on my new DataTable, initially. It came up with 0 when I looked at `.Rows.Count` on my new table. Since I was going to need to create columns on my table and add them, I just created a `NewRow()` statement and added my values to the columns on that new row directly and added that row to my table, within the loop (see my answer below).

Comment: myTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray) works only when the columns are properly specified in myTable.

Comment: Thank you.  I used ImportRow, but I discovered it was good to build the columns before hand.

Comment: As mentioned the destination table has to have the correct columns before you call ImportRow().    You can use the .Clone() method on the source DataTable to create the columns in the destination table.  Clone() doesn't copy any data, just the structure.  DataTable dtDestination = dtSource.Clone();  dtDestination.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows[0]); ...

Comment: For Me this worked  100% 
myTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray) 
My Two Tables are the same, but I need to error records in one and the non error records in the other

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dtAllOrders"];
DataTable dtSpecificOrders = dt.Clone();

DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2");

foreach (DataRow dr in orderRows)
{
    dtSpecificOrders.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. although the answer provided by @JoshBerke was correct you need to clone the original table as in your example for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

```
yourTable.ImportRow(dataRow);
```

It's because the row you're copying doesn't have the same `TableName`:

For example, try:

```
Table1.TableName = "Table1";
Table2.TableName = "Table2";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSpecificOrders.rows)
{
   dtSpecificOrders.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can add anything to what you are iterating, as you are iterating through it.

Comment: IMO, this is the most important answer on this page.  Suppose you want to change the value of one field then add another record with all other fields the same.  If you use dt.NewRow it will clear the item array.  Many posts suggest you clone the datatable and row to preserve the values, but that is not necessary if you use this form of the Rows.Add method.  Otherwise you need the dt.AcceptChanges() method, all of which can be avoided by this one, simple, perfect line of code posted seven years ago.  I could not find this answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the cleanest/quickest/easiest/most elegant solution, but it is a brute force one that I created to get the job done in a similar scenario:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dtAllOrders"];
DataTable dtSpecificOrders = new DataTable();

// Create new DataColumns for dtSpecificOrders that are the same as in "dt"
DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
DataColumn dcName = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
dtSpecificOrders.Columns.Add(dtID);
dtSpecificOrders.Columns.Add(dcName);

DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2");

foreach (DataRow dr in orderRows)
{
    DataRow myRow = dtSpecificOrders.NewRow();  // <-- create a brand-new row
    myRow[dcID] = int.Parse(dr["ID"]);
    myRow[dcName] = dr["Name"].ToString();
    dtSpecificOrders.Rows.Add(myRow);   // <-- this will add the new row
}
```

The names in the DataColumns must match those in your original table for it to work.  I just used "ID" and "Name" as examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy the DataTable using Copy method
dt1 = dt.Copy();

then remove all the rows form dt1 using Clear method
dt1.Rows.Clear();

Then start importing it again

```
foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
{
   dt1.ImportRow(myRow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `CopyToDataTable`

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dtAllOrders"];
DataTable dtSpecificOrders = new DataTable();

DataTable orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2").CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What is orderRows supposed to be here?

Comment: A new DataTable of the selected rows from `dt`, Avi.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [LoadDataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow?view=net-7.0) (object.ItemArray, true).

```
myDS.myTable.LoadDataRow(myTableRow.ItemArray, true);
```

This will not only add a new row but will in fact see if the row already exists and simply update the existing. For me this makes more sense as it is more versatile as simply ImportRow even though Import is faster if you know that indeed you are always adding a new item to the collection and not simply adding an existing item with updated values.

Comment: I use this technique when I have two forms that communicate with each other. The main form has a list of all items and the child form is for only updating or creating a new item and handles the work with validation and saving to database. When the child form returns I dont need to load all the items from the database again, but I simply load the data row that was just sent to the db from the child form

Answer (score 0):

you can give some id to the columns and name it uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

One should be careful when faced with this error especially in binding scenarios. This may well be an indicator that **you might bind to a wrong DataTable**.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `DataTable dt2 = dt.clone();` worked for me...