# Quick way to insert the same record as copy using Tableadapter

Tags: c#, ado.net, tableadapter

I have a datatable with a bunch of fields, and it's filled data by tableadapter. Usually, records that need to be inserted are a little bit different (only id). I don't want user to retypes everything again so, is there a quick way to insert current record into database. Notice that all my insert, update and delete operations are based on my tableadapter.

```
//Get only one last record that has been added when the form load.
bookTableAdapter.FillByLastID(bookDataSet.dtBook);

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  bookBindingSource.AddNew();  
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Validate();
  bookBindingSource.EndEdit();
  bookTableAdapter.Update(bookDataSet.dtBook);
}
```

Comment: Some code example would be great. Because its not clear how you do the update work. Do u post the whole table or what?

Comment: I just the update method on my datadapater. I post one record at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to copy row:

```
        DataRow row = table.Rows[0]; // row you want to copy

        DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray.ToArray();
        newRow["Id"] = 10;  // change Id

        table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: What is GUid.NewGuid();? I've got a error message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid'to type 'System.IConvertable'. Couldn't store <sdldslfka-sd2f13-...> in ID Column. Expected type is Int32

Comment: In my example Id column is type of Guid, As I see you have int there so change it to some int.See my update

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because the TableAdapter query returned more columns than a new row had, 33. My table has 32 columns. This is legacy code and database.

However, this article gave me the answer: [This Row already belongs to another table error when trying to add rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows)