# This row already belongs to another table

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datatable

I have a problem with my asp.net website, I am trying to copy a data row from one data table to another data table, but every time I am trying to do this i am getting an error:

```
This row already belongs to another table.
```

Answer (score 17):

As the error states, a `DataRow` instance is tied to its owning `DataTable` and cannot be added to another table.

Instead, use the [`ImportRow()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) to make an actual copy of the row.

Comment: Ok, Microsoft... you realize that is the case, why not, instead of throwing a smug exception, you run ImportRow in that case for us?  *sigh*

Comment: @SeanKendle: No; having add sometimes make a copy of the row with no indication would be a very bad idea.

Comment: Is there a case where saying "add row" *wouldn't* mean make a copy?  Or, where you can even use add row if it's already a member of another table?

Comment: @SeanKendle: `table.NewRow()`.  Or, remove, then re-add.

Comment: Ok, so, in my mind, my point stands.  In the case where you're saying "add this existing row (member of another table) to this other table", the language should be intelligent enough to know what you mean is "make a copy of the existing row, and add the copy to this table."  Just my opinion.  Sometimes VB.net isn't very intuitive.

Comment: @SeanKendle: No; that's exactly the opposite.  The `Add()` method everywhere adds an _existing_ instance to a collection.  Silently creating copies, especially only sometimes, is a horrible idea and is likely to lead to bugs.  To put it differently, you don't want to write `a.Add(b)`, then discover that `b` is still not in `a`.

Answer (score 4):

For Example

You need to create a new `Row` with the values from `dr` first. A `DataRow` can only belong to a single `DataTable`.

You can also use Add which takes an array of values:

```
myTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
```

Or probably even better:

```
myTable.ImportRow(dr);
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows)

Comment: This won't work directly first you need to clone the source table with destination data table