# datarow filter value to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarow

I want to insert data row filter value to datatable but it returns the following error "This row already belongs to another table." Please help me to fix this error..

This is my partial code :

```
  for (int j = 0; j < ListBox1.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    DataView DV = new DataView();
                    DV = DS1.DefaultView;
                    DV.RowFilter = "fldemployee='" + ListBox1.Items[j].Text + "' and fldassigndate = '04-07-2012'";
                    if (DV.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataTable table = DV.ToTable("sp_getallattendancesetup");
                        DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
                        DT.Rows.Add(row);

                    }

                }

                GridView1.DataSource = DT;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImportRow`

```
DT.Rows.ImportRow(row);
```

> Information from msdn: Calling NewRow adds a row to the table using
>   the existing table schema, but with default values for the row, and
>   sets the DataRowState to Added. Calling ImportRow preserves the
>   existing DataRowState along with other values in the row. If the
>   DataRow that is passed as a parameter is in a detached state, it is
>   ignored, and no exception is thrown.
>
> The new row will be added to the end of the data table.
>
> If the new row violates a Constraint it won’t be added to the data
>   table.
>
> You can get the index of the new row with as DataTable.Rows.Find and
>   DataTable.Rows.IndexOf. See DataRowCollection and Rows for more
>   information.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx)