# DataRow.RowError is not getting copied when using DataTable.Load

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I have to copy rows from one table to another. In the source table I can have RowError set on rows.
When I do this:

```
targetTable.BeginLoadData();
targetTable.Load( new DataTableReader( sourceTable ) )
targetTable.EndLoadData();
```

The target table does not get row errors copied on its rows from source table.
Can anyone tell what am I supposed to do to make it work?
Thanks.

EDIT: I do not want to lose the data already present in the target table. Nor do I want to change the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
targetTable = sourceTable.Copy();
```

Creating a reader won't give you the expected result in this case, because its (reader) goal will be extracting the value of each row, not the appendant properties.

**Update:**

In this case, you should:

```
foreach (DataRow drImport in sourceTable.Rows) {
    targetTable.ImportRow(drImport);
}
```

---

Sorry, just before posting I've seen your other observation about the reference. I'm afraid you can't have the same row (same reference) assigned to two ore more tables. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows).

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in my question. I do not want to lose the data already present in the target table. Nor do I want to change the reference. `targetTable` is referencing a DataTable in memory which is also being referenced by other components in my application.

Comment: I meant reference of `targetTable`, not the rows. :)