# Gridview-Datasource: Datatable loses all its Rows

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I've come across a rather strange behavior.

Behind my form i have my constructor which looks like this:

```
Private Property SourceDatatable As DataTable
Public Sub New()
     ' This call is required by the designer.
     InitializeComponent()

     SourceDatatable  = GetData()
     'SourceDatatable now has 500 rows
     AvailableObjects.DataSource = SourceDatatable 
End Sub
```

Right now all 500 rows are visible inside the gridview.
When the user clicks a button, then the selected row is 'copied'

```
Private Sub CopyObject_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNewObject.Click
    Dim selectedRow As Integer = GridviewAvailableObjects.GetSelectedRows().FirstOrDefault()
    If (selectedRow > 0) Then
        Dim selectedDataRow As Integer = GridviewAvailableObjects.GetRowHandle(selectedRow)
        SelectedRecords.Rows.Add(SourceDatatable.Rows(selectedDataRow))
    End If
    GridViewSelectedValues.RefreshData()
End Sub
```

The error occurs at `SourceDatatable.Rows(selectedDataRow)`. All of a sudden it has `0 rows`, Yet `selectedDataRow` refers to the correct row in the datasource(datatable). There is no interference of other Methods/Code as these 2 methods are the only ones present on the form and there is `no other code on this form`. Nor is the grid or any control accessible from outside the form.

What could cause this strange behavior? Does de `Devexpress Gridview` do anything with the datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not directly add rows from one table to another due to DataTable restrictions - it will throw the `System.ArgumentException` ("This row already belongs to another table") exception. This issue [is not specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows) to DevExpress GridView. And you can avoid it with easy via copying only "values" from the original row into another table.

This version of "copying" works to me, please review it:

```
void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var selectedRowHandles = gridViewForAllData.GetSelectedRows();
    for(int i = 0; i < selectedRowHandles.Length; i++) {
        var selectedRow = gridViewForAllData.GetDataRow(selectedRowHandles[i]);
        selectedRowsTable.Rows.Add(selectedRow.ItemArray);
    }
    gridViewForSelectedValues.RefreshData();
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles simpleButton1.Click
    Dim selectedRowHandles = gridViewForAllData.GetSelectedRows()
    For i As Integer = 0 To selectedRowHandles.Length - 1
        Dim selectedRow = gridViewForAllData.GetDataRow(selectedRowHandles(i))
        selectedRowsTable.Rows.Add(selectedRow.ItemArray)
    Next i
    gridViewForSelectedValues.RefreshData()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this works! But would there be any reason why the original datatable gets cleared?

Comment: @svranken - i believe because the data structure is broken - see the exception I mentioned.