# adding datarows from array of datarows to top of datatable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

The array is obtained by a linq query on a datatable. When I try to add it to another datatable it gives the exception that the row belongs to another table.

need to add the row to the top of the table not at the bottom

```
DataRow[] recovery_rows = Sub_DataTable.Select("ProductId = " + last_product_id.ToString() + ""); //Sub_DataTable is a datatable
for (int rev_row = 0; rev_row < recovery_rows.Count(); rev_row++)
{
    DataRow r_new = recovery_rows[rev_row];
    //  r_new = recovery_rows[rev_row];
    dt_sub.Rows.InsertAt(recovery_rows[rev_row], 0);
}
```

Comment: what is the exact exception and the line which throws it?

Comment: Sure you could google this one... Here maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722052/this-row-already-belongs-to-another-table-error-when-trying-to-add-rows

Comment: cant use that @ Michael B coz need to add the row always at top

Comment: dt_sub is a datatable i want to add the rows obtained from the select query to the top of the datatable dt_sub. the select query is used on the datatable Sub_DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a `DataRow` to another `DataTable`, it has a reference to it's `DataTable` and throws an exception if you change the table.

You can use [`DataTable.ImportRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx) which imports the row and adds it to the end of the `DataRowCollection`. So the next  task is to move it to the first position:

```
for (int rev_row = 0; rev_row < recovery_rows.Length; rev_row++)
{
    DataRow r_new = recovery_rows[rev_row];
    dt_sub.ImportRow(r_new);
    dt_sub.Rows.RemoveAt(dt_sub.Rows.Count - 1);
    dt_sub.Rows.InsertAt(r_new, 0);
}
```